# Compiling kernel, ld doesn't have the -T option

Tags: macos, bash, build, kernel

I made a custom bash script for assembling, compiling, and linking the kernel but when it gets to the line for linking i run into an error (see below). Im running this on OSX, newest build so im not sure why. Any suggestions?

> ld: unknown option: -T

My script:

```
echo Now assembling, compiling, and linking your kernel:
nasm -f aout -o start.o start.asm
gcc -Wall -O -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -nostdinc -fno-       builtin -I./include -c -o main.o main.c

ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin start.o
echo Done!
```

Comment: I suggest you to provide more info. Your build script for example.

Comment: and what you think `-T` option should do? I don't see such option in man.

Comment: ld -T is meant for running linker scripts, but it seems that ld doesnt have that option any more

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to create your own build scripts, have you managed to get the OSX kernel to build with its own scripts? [This site](http://shantonu.blogspot.com/) by one of Apple's kernel engineers tells you how it's done.

Comment: Because this isnt the xnu kernel, this is my own.

Comment: I suspect you're trying to build an ELF kernel? The binutils and gcc on OSX produce Mach-O binaries. You'll need to build your own custom GCC toolchain to cross-compile to the Linux/ELF ABI.